# Comparing two ACF values in a WP post loop

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a dedicated page for every team member on my website. The title of the page is their first and last name. For every post on my site, I have two ACF 'author' fields. I'm trying to write a query to determine if the current team member has any posts where author_1 or author_2 contains their name.

I'm currently getting 0 posts returned even though I'm positive I should be getting some. Below is my code.

```
function hide_cotw_heading(){
    $title = get_the_title();
    global $post;

    $latest_posts= get_posts( array(
        'category' => 9,
        'meta_query' => array(
            'relation' => 'OR',
            array(
                'key'     => 'author_1',
                'value'   => $title,
                'compare' => 'LIKE',
            ),
            array(
                'key'     => 'author_2',
                'value'   => $title,
                'compare' => 'LIKE',
            ),
        )
    ) );

      if($latest_posts){
        return 'Has posts';
      } else{
        return 'No posts';
      }
}
```

Comment: have you tried RLIKE compare parameter instead of LIKE?

Comment: Just tried and didn't seem to make a difference. For what it's worth, my 'author_1' and 'author_2' fields return an array of the field's label and value. As I understand it, when doing the meta query comparison, that array is basically just a string, so it should still be finding the name label in that string

Comment: But the label is not a property of the individual field _data_ stored on the posts though, is it? That is a general property of the field _definition_. Have you _checked_ what the meta data table actually contains?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have revised your code, so please try this one

```
function hide_cotw_heading() {
    $title = get_the_title();

    $args = array(
        'post_status'   => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page'=> -1, // Retrieve all matching posts
        'category'      => 9,
        'meta_query'    => array(
            'relation' => 'OR',
            array(
                'key'     => 'author_1',
                'value'   => $title,
                'compare' => '=',
            ),
            array(
                'key'     => 'author_2',
                'value'   => $title,
                'compare' => '=',
            ),
        )
    );

    $latest_posts = get_posts($args);

    if ($latest_posts) {
        return 'Has posts';
    } else {
        return 'No posts';
    }
}
```

Here is updated code that will work with the ACF array

```
function hide_cotw_heading() {
    $title = get_the_title();

    // Query for all posts in the category
    $args = array(
        'post_status'   => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page'=> -1,
        'category'      => 9,
    );

    $all_posts = get_posts($args);
    $relevant_posts = [];

    foreach ($all_posts as $post) {

        $author_1 = get_field('author_1', $post->ID);
        $author_2 = get_field('author_2', $post->ID);

        if ((isset($author_1['label']) && $author_1['label'] === $title) ||
            (isset($author_2['label']) && $author_2['label'] === $title)) {
            $relevant_posts[] = $post;
        }
    }

    if (!empty($relevant_posts)) {
        return 'Has posts';
    } else {
        return 'No posts';
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately it still does not work. The 'author_1' and 'author_2' ACF fields have both a value AND a label. ACF is returning this as an array. What I'm really looking to check is the label, not the value. Any thoughts on this? I tried using 'LIKE' as well with your code to no avail. I was told previously that the array being returned is basically converted to a string when calling that value in the meta query.

Comment: I have updated the code. please check

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're encountering likely stems from how Advanced Custom Fields (ACF) stores the data for select fields, like your 'author_1' and 'author_2'. ACF stores them as serialized arrays, which can complicate direct queries using WordPress's meta_query. When you're trying to match against a specific part of this array (like the label), a standard meta_query won't suffice, as it's not designed to parse serialized arrays or target specific elements within them.

Given that ACF stores the label and value as an array and meta_query treats this array as a string, using 'LIKE' might not be effective because the serialized string's format can vary. However, my approach to work around this is to retrieve all posts and then manually filter them based on the label. This can be less efficient but might be necessary given the data structure.

```
function hide_cotw_heading() {
    $title = get_the_title();
    $matching_posts = array();

    $args = array(
        'post_status'   => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => -1, 
        'category'      => 9,
        
    );

    $all_posts = get_posts($args);

    foreach ($all_posts as $post) {
        $author_1_data = get_field('author_1', $post->ID); 
        $author_2_data = get_field('author_2', $post->ID);

      
        if (($author_1_data && $author_1_data['label'] === $title) ||
            ($author_2_data && $author_2_data['label'] === $title)) {
            $matching_posts[] = $post;
        }
    }

    return count($matching_posts) > 0 ? 'Has posts' : 'No posts';
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this code causes a critical error on my site.. But I like the thought process here of just querying all posts and then comparing after the fact. I should be able to work with this!

Comment: Sure, I will update the answer with it .